# Writing private files created by an android app

Tags: android, file, adb

I want to overwrite private data files on Android.
[To read and pull files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5137923/1287856), I already have an answer.

```
adb pull data/data/com.myapplication.package/files/myfile.extension
```

But now, I tried to push the file back after home-made changes:

```
adb push myfile.extension data/data/com.myapplication.package/files/myfile.extension
```

I get a "`Permission denied`" error.
I tried to login on the shell and then change the permissions:

```
adb shell
chmod 777 data/data/com.myapplication.package/files/myfile.extension
```

I got a `Operation not permitted` error.
Any idea on how to overwrite the existing file on the tablet ?

Comment: You can only do that on the emulator or a rooted phone, if you have `su`. Those files are called private because they're just that: Private.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
adb shell
run-as com.myapplication.package
chmod 777 files
chmod 777 files/myfile.extension
```

The `run-as` command allows you to execute shell commands with your app's rights. You can only use it on debuggable apps, which yours should be if you're developing it.